# In PHP why is true cast 1 and false cast an empty string?

Tags: php, casting, boolean

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).

Why isn't FALSE cast to "0"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cast to an int, then to a string, it prints 0's..

```
$x=false;
print (string)(int)$x;
```

Prints 0. You can, of course, omit the string type cast as it's done by print anyway.