# PDO-MySQL: Boolean values get converted to 1 or empty string on prepared statement binding

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysql-json

I'm trying to insert some boolean values into JSON-type columns.

```
$taskSql = "INSERT INTO Tasks (data, taskListId) VALUES (JSON_OBJECT('title', :title, 'done', :done), :taskListId)";
$taskStatement = $connection->prepare($taskSql);
$taskStatement->execute([":title" => $task->title, ":done" => $task->done, ":taskListId" => $id]);
```

Which results in following SQL being executed.

```
-- $task->done is false
INSERT INTO Tasks (data, taskListId) VALUES (JSON_OBJECT('title', 'New Task', 'done', ''), '12')
-- $task->done is true
INSERT INTO Tasks (data, taskListId) VALUES (JSON_OBJECT('title', 'New Task', 'done', '1'), '12')
```

Is there a way to make PDO turn those into `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the SQL-statement, which would then convert them into proper JSON-boolean-values.

EDIT:

I've  now tried using `bindParam` and `bindValue` instead of the argument to `execute`. Those don't fix the problem as PDO still converts the boolean values to `0` or `1`.

EDIT: Looks like there is an [11 year old bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57157), that still hasn't been addressed.

Comment: Are the real values of `$task->done` :  "true" or "false" ?

Comment: When calling bind... are you using `PDO::PDO_PARAM_BOOL`?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui They are genuine booleans, I've made sure of that.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes I am.

Comment: I have this idea, try to change the `$task->done` into a string like this : `$newDone = ($task->done) ? 'true' : 'false';`

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui That would save as JSON strings rather than booleans. I don't want to do that.

Comment: the problem here is that in `mysql` Boolean types are defined as, and i quote, "These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:"

Comment: Yes, but they are not in JSON. And we are talking about JSON booleans not SQL booleans.

Comment: All PDO would need to do is insert TRUE or FALSE (Standard SQL values) for boolean bindings and MySQL would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endet up changing the insert line to

```
INSERT INTO Tasks (data, taskListId) VALUES (JSON_OBJECT('title', :title, 'done', :done = TRUE || :done = '1'), :taskListId);
```

Not a solution but a workaround.