# why in PHP (-1 > false) returns true?

Tags: php

as I know false is a 0

```
if(-1 > false)
    print "Here";
```

in this code if returns a true and `here` is printed

---

**WHY ?**

Comment: `(int)false == 0` i think

Comment: from the docs: `WARNING: -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: does it matter? nobody writes code like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/138954/1803347 See this answer

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's `-1` that is converted into boolean (`true`, as only `0` is treated as `false`). So the final comparison is

```
if (true > false) {
    ...
}
```

---

[Type Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) can be very unintuitive, so always try to avoid situations where you compare variables of two different types. In case of equality comparison always try to use identity operator (`===`), in case of inequality all you can do is to add a manual cast.

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2):

Please see [PHP Comparision Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) - table **Comparison with Various Types**

```
Type of Operand 1   Type of Operand 2       Result
bool or null        anything                Convert both sides to bool, FALSE < TRUE
```

So if you compare bool to anything else, then the second operand is casted to boolean true.
Also we have information here, that `FALSE < TRUE`, what exactly happens in your example.

Answer (score 1):

`<` is a numerical comparison operator, the code does loose comparison converting `-1` to true and hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
 WARNING: -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero 
 (whether negative or positive) number!
```

Check with this two code. You can get the difference

```
if(-1 > false)
  print "Here"; //This will print the `Here`

if(-1 > 0)
 print "Here"; // Not print `Here`
```

Comment: Why the hell should -1 be considered FALSE??