# Why php takes by default NULL as zero

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    $a = NULL;
    $a++;
   echo "a value is $a";
   ?>
```

It outputs:
  a value is 1.

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
echo "a values is $a";
?>

It outputs:
a value is
```

Am confused about this.. please explain me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null vs. False vs. 0 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It is PHP's Type Casting

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

PHP automatically changes type of variable depending upon the operation.

**Explanation:**

Your code

```
<?php
$a = NULL; // $a is NULL
$a++;
?>
```

But, increment `++` is applicable only to integer values, so when you write `$a++`, it automatically converts `$a` to integer and as it is `NULL`, it is set to `0` and then incremented.

Comment: This is part of "weak typing" and is based on PHP's Type Juggling rules. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

For -

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
$a++;
echo "a value is $a"; 
?>
```

When this operation is performed `$a` first converted to `integer` and gets the value `0` in it as it was containing `NULL`. So it is printing `1` as value.

For -

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
echo "a values is $a";
?>
```

No conversions are applied here as it is printed as it is. So it is printing nothing there.

Comment: Technically it's being converted to a string for outputting, it's just that null goes to an empty string, which doesn't output anything.