# strftime() returns incorrect preferred time format

Tags: php, locale, freebsd, strftime

I got PHP 7.0.8 (FPM) running on FreeBSD 10.1 and nginx. I need to display time in preferred format by the country where user resides.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
echo strftime('%X', time());
// Returns 21:23:12 (correct) because 24-hr format is preferred in Russia.

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo strftime('%X', time());
// Returns 21:23:12 (incorrect) must return 9:23:12 pm as preferred format in U.S.
```

**This looks like an issue with my server or PHP version, because
other users are getting correct results.**

`locale -a` return contains both `ru_RU.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8`.

`echo setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")` returns correct locale.

No special configuration is applied.

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

> %X    Preferred time representation based on locale, without the date

P.S. Preferred date `%x` works correctly displaying dd.mm.yyyy for Russia and mm/dd/yyyy for U.S.

Comment: works here: http://ideone.com/c1fGzZ

Comment: Doesn't work on my server, exactly same script. I have php70-7.0.8 on FreeBSD 10.1. `locale -a` returns exactly same locales installed.

Comment: `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")` returns correct locale.

Comment: its got to be an issue with the server

Comment: But `setlocale` doesn't return false (if any type of misconfiguration or error detected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same on FreeBSD 10.3:

```
php -r 'date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris"); var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"), strftime("%X", time()));'
string(11) "en_US.UTF-8"
string(8) "15:03:07"
```

First, `ls -l /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME` returns:

```
/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME@ -> ../en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_TIME
```

So en_US.UTF-8 is, in fact, a symlink to en_US.ISO8859-1.

Then, If we look into /usr/src/share/timedef/en_US.ISO8859-1.src (you need sources installed), we find:

```
#
# X_fmt
#
%H:%M:%S
```

Which explains the actual result when you would expect `%I:%M:%S %p` (or `%r`).

Possible solutions:

- <del>[fill a bug report](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/page.cgi?id=reporting.html) if you think it is relevant and/or</del><sup><sub>1</sub></sup> patch the file above then rebuild world (I guess)
- handle this specific case:

  ```
  echo strftime(0 === strpos(setlocale(LC_ALL, '0'), 'en_US') ? '%r' : '%X');
  ```
- prefer using [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/IntlDateFormatter) which does not rely on system-locales (assumed by ICU library). Eg:

  ```
  $timefmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM);
  $timefmt->format(date_create());
  ```

<sup><sup>1</sup> it seems that `X_fmt` is valued to `%I:%M:%S %p` in [trunk](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/share/timedef/) and [11-STABLE](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/11/share/timedef/)</sup>

Update:

- the commit altering `X_fmt` was [reverted](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=304496) since (ie on FreeBSD >= 11, `X_fmt` is still defined as `%H:%M:%S`)
- on FreeBSD 11, the file defining time formats is /usr/src/share/timedef/en_US.UTF-8.src (the symbolic link to en_US.ISO8859-1 locale is gone)

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US` on ubuntu 12.04:

```
% Appropriate time representation (%X)
%       "%r"
t_fmt   "<U0025><U0072>"
%
% Appropriate AM/PM time representation (%r)
%       "%I:%M:%S %p"
t_fmt_ampm "<U0025><U0049><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053><U0020>/
<U0025><U0070>"
```

Please note the `%I` in AM/PM date for %r.

the `%X` in unicode is 25 70 which is `%P`.

And from `man date` (stripped for simplicity):

```
%H     hour (00..23)

%I     hour (01..12)

%p     locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known

%P     like %p, but lower case

%r     locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., 11:11:04 PM)

%R     24-hour hour and minute; same as %H:%M

%x     locale's date representation (e.g., 12/31/99)

%X     locale's time representation (e.g., 23:13:48)
```

Reading all this file, it should work as expected so I suspect your setup use a different locale file or fallback to `C` locale (if the locale file is not there for example)

Now for `setlocale`, it will return false only in case you give a bad variable (I.e `LCAL` instead of `LCALL`) but will return what the system returns for other cases:

> Note: The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP
>   is running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function
>   returns.

On "linuxes" `setlocale` returns `NULL` which is not always seen as false (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0-in-php)) which may be a source of your problem, I can't swear as I've no FreeBSD running to confirm this point.