# PHP array_search function not working properly with return values

Tags: php

Today, I found a quite weird issue with php **array_search** function. Actually I applied the condition that, if index is **0 or greater** than it should passed the **IF** condition otherwise not but its not functioning like that.

I analysed and found, if output is **FALSE** then ( **FALSE >= 0**) its also passing the condition with comparing value, don't know why. Can anyone explain this problem ?

*It seems like not **array_search** function issue but i faced when using this function.*

```
$allowedJobCodesForCC   =   array(  "xyz", "abc");
/* output if value not found in array 
var_dump(array_search(strtolower(trim('xyzfd')), $allowedJobCodesForCC));
*/
$output = array_search(strtolower(trim('xyz')), $allowedJobCodesForCC); //output : false

/* array_search function treating false return value and passing it to the condition */
if($output >= 0){
    echo 'passed'; //it should not print this condition if return value is FALSE
}

/* correct fix if indexes are numeric */
if(is_numeric($output)){
    echo 'passed';
}
```

PHP Manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: It's not returning `false`. `array_search` returns the index at which the search value is found, or `false` when not found. The return value in your example is `0`. `0 !== false`. TL;DR - use strict comparison for the return value.

Comment: what does `echo $output` gives?

Comment: If you try with the value which does not exists then will return FALSE. You can try by using var_dump.

Comment: Okay, but when using loose comparison checks, `0 == false -> true`, whereas `0 === false -> false`.

Comment: The php manual page you’ve linked has a warning box explaining the perils of the possible return values

Comment: @fubar : I knew the condition with this case should be handle differently but why false >=0 is passing the condition ?

Comment: `$value >= 0` could be rewritten as `$value > 0 || $value == 0`. In this case, if `$value` is `false`, `false == 0` is `true`.

Comment: @fubar : So you are trying to say that its a bug in php library ? which is treating FALSE same as 0.

Comment: No, definitely not. PHP is a loosely typed language. `0` is falsy, so this is expected behaviour. Just use strict comparisons, per my previous comments.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh Kindly go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0-in-php  hoping it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`I analysed and found, if output is FALSE then ( FALSE >= 0) its also passing the condition with comparing value, don't know why. Can anyone explain this problem ?`

Take a look at **Comparison with Various Types** table at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

According to this table, if you compare boolean with any other type, both values are **converted** to boolean and then compared. In your case integer `0` is converted to `FALSE` and eventually php compares `FALSE >= FALSE`.
Since `FALSE` is greater or **equal** to `FALSE` you condition returns true.

Comment: Its seems correct but still have a question in mind, Is that a logical or a PHP bug ?

Comment: It's the intended and documented behavior, so definitely not a PHP bug.
PHP is loosely typed language, so developers had to find a way to compare different types. That's just how they handled it

Comment: Logically, if you actually do compare boolean with int, I'd say that this behavior is quite logical. But comparison itself does not make much sense.
However question if it's logical or not seems more like opinion-based

Comment: I did little research on it with javascript and its behaving same with boolean value (false) but not behaving same with string value.

/* Javascript Code */
var test  = 'sdf';
 if(test >= 0){
  alert('hi');
 }

/* PHP Code */
 $test  = 'sdf';
 if($test >= 0){
  echo '==';
 }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `===` as it checks the value and also checks for the type of the value so that it won't pass the condition as it was happening in your case. It was checking for the value but wasn't checking its type which was creating the problem as it was treating `false` as a string which is obviously true condition (value of string is greater than 0).

```
$allowedJobCodesForCC = array("xyz", "abc");
/* output if value not found in array 
  var_dump(array_search(strtolower(trim('xyzfd')), $allowedJobCodesForCC));
 */
$output = array_search(strtolower(trim('xyz')), $allowedJobCodesForCC); //output : false

/* array_search function treating false return value and passing it to the condition */
if ($output === False && $output !== 0) {
    echo 'not passed'; //it should not print this condition if return value is FALSE
} else {
    echo 'passed';
}
```

Comment: I know the solution but i am asking why its happening ?

Comment: as it it return false you are comparing using  `==` which only checks the value and here in your case `false` is treated as a string and `any string > 0` always that's why

Comment: I did not mentioned == to anywhere.

Comment: `>=` i mean this one only, it is checking the value

Comment: you can do var_dump to check datatype. Its returning boolean not string type data.

Comment: thats what i am saying it not checking for the type, only the value, `false` is just a string unless you mention or check its type explicitly

Comment: but false value never equals to 0 and condition is passing it as equals to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181522/discussion-between-exterminator-and-kuldeep-singh).